# How to Modify Category for approved application in appstore

Tags: ios, app-store

I submitted my app to the appstroe, that is approved from appstore and in ready to sale status. but i want to change primary and second category text, is it possible. please inform me

Answer (score 2):

No we can't change once app approved. if you want to change that you should add new version of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update the category when you app is in an "editable" state (that is, when you're uploading a new version for review).

Take a look at the "Version-Level Properties" section of the [iTunes Connect App Properties webpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html), and you'll see that "Categories" is listed as "Locked" and not editable.  According to that page, "Locked properties are only editable when your app is in an editable state."